# How to run database driven mail queues in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I want to queue and send mails with `database` based queue driver. I can send emails with that:

```
Mail::to('someone@example.com')->send(new ForgotPassword($first_name, $link));
```

This also works (I see that a row is inserted in `jobs` table).

```
Mail::to('someone@example.com')->queue(new ForgotPassword($first_name, $link));
```

But I couldn't find the way to run queues and send emails in the background.

This is not working:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

How can I do that?

Note: It is Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually run the queue. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide insights on your error (check laravel.log file). It may be because one or both of your variables is not made available to your mailable class, so don't forget to define

```html
public $first_name;
public $link;
```

in your *ForgotPassword* class and set the class' constructor.